# Kafka too many open files, many tiny logs, with high ulimit and about 5k segments

Tags: apache-kafka

It keeps having Kafka reporting "Too many open files". I just restarted clean, but after 10 minutes or so I end up with

```
lsof | grep cp-kafka | wc -l:
454225
```

process limits:

```
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units
Max cpu time              unlimited            unlimited            seconds
Max file size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max data size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max stack size            8388608              unlimited            bytes
Max core file size        0                    unlimited            bytes
Max resident set          unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max processes             96186                96186                processes
Max open files            800000               800000               files
Max locked memory         16777216             16777216             bytes
Max address space         unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max file locks            unlimited            unlimited            locks
Max pending signals       96186                96186                signals
Max msgqueue size         819200               819200               bytes
Max nice priority         0                    0
Max realtime priority     0                    0
Max realtime timeout      unlimited            unlimited            us
```

I have set retention.hours to -1, as I want to keep all logs from the past. In my server.properties I had segment files of 100mb, but for some reason, Kafka makes 10mb logs. The strange thing is, I "only" have a relatively low number of files in the log directory.

```
find | wc -l
5884
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong here.

I installed the confluent-kafka deb packages on Ubuntu 18.04.

- kafka 2.0
- messages are about 500bytes each
- auto create topic is true

One directory, are my messages too small for the timeindex?

```
rw-r--r--  1  2.2K Sep 30 10:03 00000000000000000000.index  
rw-r--r--  1  1.2M Sep 30 10:03 00000000000000000000.log  
rw-r--r--  1  3.3K Sep 30 10:03 00000000000000000000.timeindex  
rw-r--r--  1   560 Sep 30 10:03 00000000000000004308.index  
rw-r--r--  1  293K Sep 30 10:03 00000000000000004308.log  
rw-r--r--  1    10 Sep 30 10:03 00000000000000004308.snapshot  
rw-r--r--  1   840 Sep 30 10:03 00000000000000004308.timeindex  
rw-r--r--  1   10M Sep 30 10:03 00000000000000005502.index  
rw-r--r--  1   97K Sep 30 10:04 00000000000000005502.log  
rw-r--r--  1    10 Sep 30 10:03 00000000000000005502.snapshot  
rw-r--r--  1   10M Sep 30 10:03 00000000000000005502.timeindex
```

Also added the following lines in server config; index remain 10Mb max

```
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.segment.index.bytes=1073741824
```

BTW, I am sending messages with timestamps in the past, with log retention of 1000 years.

Comment: One possible issue can be that your producers are creating new connections for every message. Can you check for the number of open connections to Kafka server? If they are too high consider pooling of batching messages.

Comment: Tiny logs seems fixed by issueing messages with Datime.Default (I am using C#). I now haven't got the tiny logs. How can I see the incoming connections? I am lingering 2 seconds to batch messages.

Comment: No more issues since using current Timestamp, maybe a kafka bug somewhere?